# Calculating Mean average precision of a model that does not predict confidence value

Tags: python

How can I calculate the mean average precision in the scenario where my model does not provide confidence values and we only have confusion matrix which is generated from the output? Is it possible?

Comment: Question for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ not SO.

Comment: More information is needed, This site contains questions to solve programming issues. If you can provide python program, or describe supporting run-times and libraries, then this question might be more easy to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you post what library you are using.

But generally speaking, since you have the confusion matrix, you also have the false positive and false negative numbers that you can use to calculate the precision:

Precision = True positive/ ( true positive + false positive) 

or in short TP/(TP+FP)

Comment: Respected sir,
I using no library but using some kind of thresholding which decides the Confusion matrix.